# MobX React replacement for componentWillReact() for triggering layout animations

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react, layout-animation

It was once [recommended to use `componentWillReact()` to trigger layout animations](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/332) in response to changes in observable values, like so:

```
componentWillReact() {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    }
```

However, `componentWillReact()` has been removed in mobx-react@6.

What is the recommended replacement?  My *observable* class should know nothing about it's *observer*, so I'm looking for a similar event-driven solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, and you have a chance to use functional component, try the `useLayoutEffect` hook instead of `componentWillReact`, declare observable value as its deps, and call `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` in hook's callback, like this:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
}, [store.something]);
```